# Python Pandas Group by c3 find max of column 2 and get column 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I tried reflecting some complex SQL operations in python. started with intially - requirement is to find out the EMP_ID who is getting the Maximum salary by the department wise.
3 steps:

1. Groupby(Dept)
2. Max(Salary) - in each department
3. get(Emp_Id) - in each department

### Sample file.csv

```
EMP_ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SAL,DEPT,LOC
1,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
2,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
3,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
4,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME-DATA,bhmd
5,ghk,3,PTBP,24,IME-DATA,bhmd
6,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
7,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
8,ghk,3,PTBP,29,IME-NA,bhmd
9,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
10,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME-NA,bhmd
```

Code i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
df=pd.read_csv("SAM_JOINS.csv",sep=",")
go=df["EMP_ID"]+df["AGE"]
df["SYSTEM_REVENUE"]=go
print (df)
b=df.groupby(["DEPT"],as_index=False)
gb1=b['DEPT'].agg({'Count':np.size})
print(gb1)
```

but failed to get the max(salary) and emp_id by each department wise.
Please help me in this regards as i am new bee to python pandas.

Comment: Can you post your desired output, it's unclear from your explanation exactly what you want, for instance doesn't `b.max()` give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [group.transform method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).

Basically, this line:

```
df['DEPT_MAX_SAL'] = df.groupby('DEPT')['SAL'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
```

puts the department max salary on every line and then all you have to do is subset from there.  I've included an IPython of the implementation with your data.  Note that since your example data does not have a lot of variation on the `SAL` field, the example doesn't look particularly clean.

```
IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

In [1]: from StringIO import StringIO
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: 

In [2]: # Create data set for pandas to read from
   ...: data = """EMP_ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SAL,DEPT,LOC
   ...: 1,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 2,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 3,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 4,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME-DATA,bhmd
   ...: 5,ghk,3,PTBP,24,IME-DATA,bhmd
   ...: 6,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 7,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 8,ghk,3,PTBP,29,IME-NA,bhmd
   ...: 9,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME,bhmd
   ...: 10,ghk,3,PTBP,23,IME-NA,bhmd"""
   ...: data = StringIO(data)
   ...: 

In [3]: # Load dataset
   ...: df = pd.read_csv(data)
   ...: print df
   ...: 
   EMP_ID NAME  AGE ADDRESS  SAL      DEPT   LOC
0       1  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
1       2  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
2       3  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
3       4  ghk    3    PTBP   23  IME-DATA  bhmd
4       5  ghk    3    PTBP   24  IME-DATA  bhmd
5       6  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
6       7  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
7       8  ghk    3    PTBP   29    IME-NA  bhmd
8       9  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd
9      10  ghk    3    PTBP   23    IME-NA  bhmd

In [4]: # Create new column of department max salary
   ...: df['DEPT_MAX_SAL'] = df.groupby('DEPT')['SAL'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
   ...: print df
   ...: 
   EMP_ID NAME  AGE ADDRESS  SAL      DEPT   LOC  DEPT_MAX_SAL
0       1  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
1       2  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
2       3  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
3       4  ghk    3    PTBP   23  IME-DATA  bhmd            24
4       5  ghk    3    PTBP   24  IME-DATA  bhmd            24
5       6  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
6       7  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
7       8  ghk    3    PTBP   29    IME-NA  bhmd            29
8       9  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
9      10  ghk    3    PTBP   23    IME-NA  bhmd            29

In [5]: # Subset to show only employees with max salary in department
   ...: print df[df['SAL'] == df['DEPT_MAX_SAL']]
   EMP_ID NAME  AGE ADDRESS  SAL      DEPT   LOC  DEPT_MAX_SAL
0       1  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
1       2  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
2       3  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
4       5  ghk    3    PTBP   24  IME-DATA  bhmd            24
5       6  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
6       7  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
7       8  ghk    3    PTBP   29    IME-NA  bhmd            29
8       9  ghk    3    PTBP   23       IME  bhmd            23
```

Comment: It  really worked..Suppose if the formula is x = a/b where b is the denominator,count of that particular dept_id. a is Numerator i,e emp_id based on the max(salary) for each department. This calculation should be on all the records. I am almost near.. Just need a push..Plz help me

Comment: Unfortunately, your data isn't clean enough to support this easily.  Your data shows multiple employees with the max salary in any given department so you need to specify what you want the output to look like, if you want duplicate records or some kind of field with the ids concatenated?